# How is map reduce being used to create pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I was looking at the code on this page:

https://ahmedbesbes.com/how-to-mine-newsfeed-data-and-extract-interactive-insights-in-python.html

```
news = pd.DataFrame(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y ,map(lambda r: r['articles'], responses)))
```

Can someone explain this line ? What is the map / reduce operation doing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lambda` it's a function only. And `map` that will apply that function in every element in the list. `reduce` will make the list in to a single value based on the function.

This operation describe in a small example,

```
In [2]: res
Out[2]: 
[{'articles': 124, 'other': 234},
 {'articles': 124, 'other': 234},
 {'articles': 124, 'other': 234}]

In [3]: map(lambda r: r['articles'], res)
Out[3]: [124, 124, 124]

In [4]: reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[124, 124, 124])
Out[4]: 372
```

Hope you understand this,